# Repeated calling of a ParametricNDSolve result in a faster way?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, performance-tuning, compile, parametric-functions

I recently learned of `ParametricNDSolve` and found that I need to compute it once and then call its result `sol` at different parameters `x,y` from `rmat` many times in the following example code. But always only evaluated at the same grid `ttlist` of the ODE time variable `t`, if this is relevant at all.

It turns out to be the bottleneck of my task. In reality I have much larger `Ntt` and `Nr`, so I need to speed it up as much as possible. (The form of `eqs` doesn't matter here.) Therefore I was wondering if ***any*** speed optimization possible? Either using `Compile` or not is fine.

Not sure if this is a stupid question as the result of `ParametricNDSolve` is probably not compilable. Just out of hope and curiosity...

```
eqs = {I Derivative[1][B1][t] == Abs[B1[t]]^2 (m B1[t] + B3[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + 
     Abs[B2[t]]^2 (m B1[t] + B3[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + (B1[t] Conjugate[B3[t]] + B2[t] Conjugate[B4[t]]) (-m B3[t] + 
        B1[t] (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])), 
   I Derivative[1][B2][t] == Abs[B1[t]]^2 (m B2[t] + B4[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + 
     Abs[B2[t]]^2 (m B2[t] + B4[t] (x - I y + Cos[t] - I Sin[t])) + (B1[t] Conjugate[
          B3[t]] + B2[t] Conjugate[B4[t]]) (-m B4[t] + B2[t] (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])), 
   I Derivative[1][B3][t] == B1[t] (m (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) + (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + Abs[B4[t]]^2) (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])) + 
     B3[t] (-m (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + Abs[B4[t]]^2) + (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) (x + Cos[t] - I (y + Sin[t]))), 
   I Derivative[1][B4][t] == B2[t] (m (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + 
           B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) + (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + Abs[B4[t]]^2) (x + I y + Cos[t] + I Sin[t])) + 
     B4[t] (-m (Abs[B3[t]]^2 + Abs[B4[t]]^2) + (B3[t] Conjugate[B1[t]] + B4[t] Conjugate[B2[t]]) (x + Cos[t] - I (y + Sin[t])))};

ic = {B1[-tmax] == 1, B2[-tmax] == 0, B3[-tmax] == 0, B4[-tmax] == 1};
var = {B1, B2, B3, B4};

tmax = 25; m = 0.4;
ttmax = tmax; ttmesh = ttmax/4; ttlist = Table[tt, {tt, -ttmax, ttmax, ttmesh}];
Ntt = Length@ttlist; Nr = 4;
rmat = RandomReal[1, {Nr, Nr, Ntt, Ntt, 2}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, ic}, Outer[#2[#] &, ttlist, var], {t, -tmax, tmax}, Element[#, Reals] & /@ {x, y}];

data = ParallelTable[
   With[{rxy = rmat[[ix, iy]]}, 
    Module[{Amat = 
       Table[Apply[sol, rxy[[it1, it2]]][[it1]], {it1, Ntt}, {it2, Ntt}]}, 
Total[Amat, 2](*example of much faster computation that follows*)]], {ix, Nr}, {iy, Nr}];
data // Abs // MinMax
```

Comment: As I previously advised, if you're interested in compiling stuff, you should familiarize yourself with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101). Currently, `ParametricFunction[]` (which is the head of what `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` returns) isn't in there.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I note that in my question. But still hoping for any possible improvement.

Comment: @xiaohuamao It is not slow code, it takes seconds on my laptop. How you supposed   improve it, to milliseconds?

Comment: @AlexTrounev In reality I have much larger `Ntt` and `Nr`, so I need to speed it up as much as possible.

Comment: @xiaohuamao Can you tell what actually do you try to compute? Your `data` looks like `{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}`.  How we can compare faster code with this one?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sorry, the bottleneck part is the calculation of `Amat` inside `Module` inside `data`. I need this and then some other computation that is much faster and hence I just put `1` as a placeholder.

Comment: @xiaohuamao It is okay that you compute `Amat`,  but you code is not optimized. Let suppose that we can do it 10-100 times faster. Then we can compare final result with your `data`, But your `data` not shows any result dependent on `Amat`. Can you put some function instead of 1  so that we can compare `data`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sure, I updated the last piece of the code. Hope it helps to compare and there could be some speed-up.

Comment: Reduce the `PrecisionGoal`?  Below `PrecisionGoal -> 5` I run into trouble on the test code (error is too large).  With a setting of `5`, I get 2-3 digits of precision in the `MinMax` result. It's only a modest savings of time (~40%).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. This is a useful suggestion in certain cases.